# ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified: Azure App Service/Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I deployed a **Spring Boot Backend Application** on **Azure App Service**. The deployment also uses **GitHub Actions**. After the deployment was successful, I tried to use the URL generated by Azure App Service- **app-service-name.azurewebsites.net**
But I keep on getting the following error-

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
```

**Errors-**
On checking the insights, I found out that following errors raised when I make a request using the url-

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is an identity or timestamp column, or alternatively if none of the previous conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow addition of this column. Column 'firstname' cannot be added to non-empty table 'users' because it does not satisfy these conditions.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:872)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:767)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375)
```

**and**

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table [comments] add [comment_id] int not null" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:608)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
```

My db structure (and comments table) is-
[image: users table]
[image: comments structure]

- I don't understand why the alter-table query is being executed on making an unrelated HTTPS request.
- When I first ran the application from local computer, following queries were run to create comments table-

```
Hibernate: create table [comments] ([comment_id] int not null, [description] varchar(200), [postid] int, [userid] int, primary key ([comment_id]))
Hibernate: create sequence [comments_seq] start with 1 increment by 50
Hibernate: alter table [comments] add constraint [FKmdd04pxs9r8tjcudlpqyrerju] foreign key ([postid]) references [post]
Hibernate: alter table [comments] add constraint [FK438ln47jx9ti2rl766iogqr79] foreign key ([userid]) references [users]
```

**Also, when I created the database, all the tables were created without any exception and when I use localhost to make requests, I do not face any problem. This problem occurs only with Azure App Service generated URL.**
I am adding application insights snapshot for failures-

[image]

Please help me in finding why this issue occurs.

Comment: Did you have an existing database schema on your local database or you started from scratch? It seems your App Service deployment ran a database migration on a preexisting database and that migration tried to add new columns to a table. If your local deployment started from scratch, than the table was created with all needed columns, so you didn't get the same error as the server.

Comment: I tried to things- First, I created the database, added the connection string to my project, ran the project from vscode on my computer. All tables were created in the db on Azure. I worked with that db from localhost, everthing worked fine. But, when I created app service after this and used the url, I got the error. Second, I created the App Service and then ran it. On making the request with the generated URL, all tables were created followed by error.

Comment: @coder001 Is it possible for you to provide your code to check the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to provide the code. But I can answer any queries which might help to rectify this issue. Thank You.